# How to make dynamic server IP config in Android?

Tags: php, android

I am new at Android. Now, I am developing android application with webservice. To connect the server (php code) I use this AppConfig.class

```
public class AppConfig {
private static String serverIp="http://100.100.x.xxx";
    public static String URL_LOGIN = serverIp+"/myAndro/login.php";
}
```

From that code, I have a problem when I want to use different server IP address, so I always change my android code (the value of `serverIp` variabel). 
Has Anyone an idea to make that value dynamicaly (without change that hard code when want to use another server/IP address)? The good answer is appreciated.

Comment: Where are the values of `serverIp` coming from?

Comment: that IP comes from my local server. But that server for about 1 month later will be public. So the IP will be changed.

Comment: In that case maybe just setup a dynamic dns (DDNS) for the value (eg. then it could be http://dynamic.hostname.com/ which resolves back to http://100.100.x.xxx).